# Paging Entities (of Aggregates) in Repository with Entity Framework (EF)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern

Suppose I have the following aggregate root:

```
public class Aggregate
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    public List<Entity> Entities {get; set;}
}
```

And the following repository:

```
public class AggregateRepository
{
   public Aggregate GetPaged(int Id)
   {
     return db.Aggregate
              .Include(x=>x.Entities)
              .Find(id)             
   }
}
```

**Question**: how can I get a paged and sort list of entities? Which is the best approach to get the entities paged and sorted, but also with the aggregate information?

**Edited:**

What are you think about the following approach?

```
public class AggregateRepository
    {
       public IEnumerable<Entity> GetEntitiesPaged(int id)
       {
         return db.Aggregate
                  .Include(x=>x.Aggregate)
                  .Where(x=>x.Id = id)
                  .Select(x=>x.Entities)
                  .Take(20);        
       }
    }
```

Instead of return an aggregate object, I can receive a list of entities (20 entities, in this case) with aggregate object included. Is it a good approach working with an aggregate in DDD pattern?

Comment: In order to give you a useful answer I'd like to know what you are trying to achieve with paged and sorted list of Entities.
- Do you need a paged and sorted list of Entities in your write or read model?
- Are you going to use this page to show Entities to the user?
- Are you going to read (query) Entities page by page in order to enforce some invariant in your domain?

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that you should avoid querying your domain model.

Rather use a specialized query layer with a read model if required; else something more raw such as `DataRow`.

***Update***:

You should try not to create aggregates when querying.  This means not accessing a repository.  A query layer would look something like this:

```
public interface ISomethingQuery
{
    IEnumerable<SomethingDto> GetPage(SearchSPecification specification, int pageNumber);
    // -or-
    IEnumerable<DataRow> GetPage(SearchSPecification specification, int pageNumber);
}
```

You would then use an implementation of this query interface to get the required data for display/reporting.

Comment: Thanks for you answer :) When you say: "use a specialized query layer with a read model", are you saying to do that after to get the all data in memory (after to call the GetPaged() method), right? In that way, if my entities have a lot of data, the performance will decrease and I want to avoid this. The DataRow option is not a option for now because I would have to change the application approach and I don´t want to do that. 
I edited my post. If you want to comment I appreciate that :)

Comment: I have updated the answer to shed more light on the matter :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should separate your write-side(commands) from the read side (queries), which called [CQRS](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html). You can take a look this [example](http://danielwhittaker.me/2014/10/02/cqrs-step-step-guide-flow-typical-application/).

But if you just want to get a paged and sorted list of entities, you can use the following approach.

```
public ICollection<Aggregate> GetSortedAggregates(AggregateListFilter filter, out int rowCount)
{
    var query = (base.Repository.CurrentSession() as ISession).QueryOver<Aggregate>();

    query = query.And(q => q.Status != StatusType.Deleted);

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.Name))
        query = query.And(q => q.Name == filter.Name);

    rowCount = query.RowCount();

    switch (filter.OrderColumnName)
    {
        case ".Name":
            query = filter.OrderDirection == OrderByDirections.Ascending ? query.OrderBy(x => x.Name).Asc : query.OrderBy(x => x.Name).Desc;
            break;
        default:
            query = filter.OrderDirection == OrderByDirections.Ascending ? query.OrderBy(x => x.Id).Asc : query.OrderBy(x => x.Id).Desc;
            break;
    }

    if (filter.CurrentPageIndex > 0)
    {
        return query
        .Skip((filter.CurrentPageIndex - 1) * filter.PageSize)
        .Take(filter.PageSize)
        .List();
    }

    return query.List();
}
```